# Connecting a different user using mongoClient connexion pool

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I 'm using a MongoClient connexion pool at the top of my app.js node.js back end, it works well:

```
 var db;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db = client.db('myDb');
        // Start the application after the database connection is ready
        app.listen(3000);
        console.log("Listening on port 3000");
    });

    app.post('/getEvaluations', function(req, res) {
        db.collection('evaluations').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(docs);

        });
    })
```

I want to build a html form, for  getting the login password, but how can I  change the MongoClient connexion with the new login password afterwards ?

For example, as long as John logs in, he needs to have READ rights to be able to call the getEvaluations web service.

Do I have to always make the connexion with no user , then only check the user session inside each of the web services ?

Or Is it possible to change the pool connexion , each time a mongoDb user logs in ( he might only have READ rights)?
Something like this ?

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://john:passwd@localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db = client.db('myDb');
    // Start the application after the database connection is ready
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

For example, let's say "John" with the password "passwd" wants to log in, how could I do ? Is there any standard code somewhere using a connexion pool ?

I also use express-session but dont understand how to use it with the connexion pool.

I can't find a mongoDb auth code using the connexion pool. There are some moogoose examples but, it is not the same .

This is the idea I've got :

The user logs in via HTTP, then if the login is ok, so a session is created, but how could i check afterwards if the user only has READ rights during all of his session  ?

This is a pseudo code, from a moongoose example, but this is not what i need, i'm using mongoClient.

```
app.get('/getAuth', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.param('email');
    var password = req.param('password');

    //authenticate input against database
        UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
          User.findOne({ email: email })
            .exec(function (err, user) {
              if (err) {
                return callback(err)
                } else if (!user) {
                var err = new Error('User not found.');
                err.status = 401;
                return callback(err);
              }
              bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
                if (result === true) {
                  return callback(null, user);
                } else {
                  return callback();
                }
              })
            });
        }
})
```

If somebody has an example code, i would really appreciate it, I don't use moogoose , but mongoClient Thank you.

or maybe, this auth web service would be better :

```
app.get('/getAuth', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.param('user');
    var password = req.param('password');
    db.authenticate(user, password, function(err, res) {
        // callback
    });
})
```

but then, what should I do with the connexion pool ? How could I reload it ?
I can't understand how to do.

**EDIT 1:** This is what I got for now : I've built a getAuth web service, with a pool connexion starting inside of it, is it the right way to do ?

```
var db;
    app.get('/getAuth', function(req, res) {

        var user = "jose";
        var password = "passwd";

        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://"+user+":"+password+"@localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
            if (err) {console.log(err)}

            else{
                db = client.db('myDb');
                // Start the application after the database connection is ready
                console.log("correct log in");
            }
        });

    })
```

how could I use a session now?

**EDIT 2 :** Seems to be working code with express-session using this doc :
https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

```
  //use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));
sess ={}; 

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------AUTH USER
    app.get('/getAuth', function(req, res) {

        var user = "jose";
        var password = "passwd";

        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://"+user+":"+password+"@localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
            if (err) {console.log(err)}

            else{
                db = client.db('myDb');


                 sess = req.session;
                /*
                * Here we have assign the 'session' to 'sess'.
                * Now we can create any number of session variable we want.
                * in PHP we do as $_SESSION['var name'].
                * Here we do like this.
                */
                sess.email = "jose.golo@gmail.com"; // equivalent to $_SESSION['email'] in PHP.
                sess.username = "jose"; // equivalent to $_SESSION['username'] in PHP.
                res.end('done');


            }
        });

    })
```

Then, in my getEvaluations web service, i 'm checking if sess contains an email, otherwize, it means that he's not logged in, so he can't access the evaluations node.js web service :

```
 app.post('/getEvaluations', function(req, res) {

        if (!sess.hasOwnProperty("email")  ){
            console.log('not logged in ');
        }else{
            db.collection('evaluations').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send(docs);
            });
        }
    })
```

If you have a better solution, please let me know . This app is front end Ionic 1 app .

**Question :**
Is it a normal behavior :
I get authenticated inside of firefox, so i can access my evaluations.
Now, I go to chrome, on the same computer , i don't have to authenticate to view the evaluations ?
Is it because it is a user Id based session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Let the user log in via a HTTP form using the POST method.
2. Try and find the user's document inside your mongo database (eg. by username). This will result in a user object containing your user's credentials and whatever rights he/she has.
3. Compare the credentials with the input provided by the log-in form (which is contained within the request object's body).
4. If the given input and previously stored credentials are equal to each other you can create a session and assign the user object to it.
5. Check if there's a session object inside the request when the user navigates to '/getEvaluations'. This session object will contain user object of the currently logged in user.
6. Respond with your Evaluations object if and only if the user has the appropriate
   rights.

You could try out authentication middleware like [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/). These will handle the sessions and its user data object for you. Here's an example using the local strategy: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example

Comment: Thank you but i've tried with db.authenticate and it doesnt exist any more

Comment: Passport.js seems nice, i will try it out, thank you